# Class dompdf.wrapper does not exist laravel 4.2.0

Tags: laravel, dompdf

I am trying to use the dompdf package with Lavarel 4.2.0 in my project authored by barryvdh, I tried installing three different versions of this package (0.6*, 0.6.1,0.5.2)

```
"name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "laravel/framework": "4.2.*",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.6",
        "barryvdh/laravel-dompdf": "0.5.2"
```

How ever each time I try to create a PDF file using

```
Route::get('/invoice', function()
{
$pdf = App::make('dompdf.wrapper');
$pdf->loadHTML('<h1>Test</h1>');
return $pdf->stream();
});
```

I get this error

```
Class dompdf.wrapper does not exist (vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php)
/ hand back the results of the functions, which allows functions to be
        // used as resolvers for more fine-tuned resolution of these objects.
        if ($concrete instanceof Closure)
        {
            return $concrete($this, $parameters);
        }

        $reflector = new ReflectionClass($concrete);

        // If the type is not instantiable, the developer is attempting to resolve
```

Answer (score 0):

I put in file `config/app.php` into `providers` section:

```
Barryvdh\DomPDF\ServiceProvider::class,
```

And into `aliases` section:

```
'PDF'       => Barryvdh\DomPDF\Facade::class,
```

And I use this in my controller:

```
use PDF;
...
$pdf = PDF::loadView('panel.cooperation-offers.pdf', $showData);
```

Here is my composer.json:

```
...
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.5.9",
    "laravel/framework": "5.2.*",
    "barryvdh/laravel-dompdf": "0.6.*"
}, ...
```

Comment: Adding this Barryvdh\DomPDF\ServiceProvider::class,
to config/app.php was enough to solve the problem.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

According to [the docs](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf/tree/0.4), we need to install the *0.4.x* versions for Laravel 4. Your project is using versions for Laravel 5.

*composer.json*:

```
"require": { 
    ... 
    "barryvdh/laravel-dompdf": "0.4.*"
}
```

To resolve the dompdf service from the container, use `'dompdf'`, not `'dompdf.wrapper'`:

```
$pdf = App::make('dompdf');
```

Or, use the `PDF` facade:

```
use PDF; 
... 
$pdf = PDF::loadHTML('<h1>Test</h1>');
```

Be sure to [register the service provider and facade](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf/tree/0.4) in *config/app.php*.